# How to start with a blank main window?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I want to write some **VBA script** so that when I start my access application the main window is blank. This is the list of things I need to be removed or hidden:

- The entire ribbon
- The status bar
- The navigation pane
- The window tabs

In addition, I want to disable the popup menu when right clicking.
I also want to disable SHIFT bypass key startup.

I basically want it to look like an application created with VB or C#.
Only if I login as admin will the disabled options be bypassed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, as noted, you can use the startup options to remove most all of the questions you have in terms of popups, the tabs etc.

To hide ribbon, qat, just use:

DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo

So, with the options setup  correct and ONE line of code, you only see your form.

Here is an resulting screen shot of using the above one line of code and options to turn off tabs (you want tabbed windows, but tabs turned off). Note how you see the windows desktop. this was all done with one line of code as per above:

[image]

Comment: Yes, but did you notice how the access window flickered and showed the toolbar at startup or not? I wanted this to look professional.

Comment: I still have this flickering problem, the ribbon briefly shows then hides. It is rather clunky. Can this be solved? I don't see any solution in any comments on this page.

Answer (score 4):

Does it need to be VBA? Why not using the normal Access Application Options?

In Access 2010 you can find them via File > Options > Current Database. Almost all the things you want can just be unchecked - see the following screenshot. The options you select there are saved with your database.

You can start the database while holding <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> which will override these start up options and show you your "normal" ribbon, status bar, navigation bar, ...

[image: Access 2010 Application Options]

Answer (score 3):

Try the following in startup function

This should do what you want

```
DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo
DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Status Bar", acToolbarNo
```

Might work with other MS Access windows elements, I just wanted to not display the parts above.

Answer (score 3):

Old thread but still useful information. Here's what I do:

```
DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo
DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Status Bar", acToolbarNo
DoCmd.NavigateTo "acNavigationCategoryObjectType"
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWindowHide
```

Put that code in a `Public Sub` called from a macro called `AutoExec`.

Disabling Window Tabs and the Shift Bypass are trickier because these need to be done by setting the database property, either through the database `Properties` or by appending a property with `CreateProperty`. Also, you need to exit and reopen the database for these changes to take effect.

I found instructions over [on techrepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-tips-for-securing-a-microsoft-access-database/) and Allen Browne has more complete instructions on [his website](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-69.html).