# Automatically open and run Macro in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a database created which has a macro that runs the queries. I got to the part wherein I did AutoExec so it runs automatically once I open but is there any way where I can have it open on its own,run the macro and close once done every 45 minutes? I'm new with Office Access and any help or insight is appreciated.

Comment: Create a Scheduled task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you close an Access database there is nothing left that can trigger another execution 45 minutes later.

Set up a Scheduled Task in your OS as Andre suggested.
An All-Access alternative would (obviously) need the Access database opened at all times, but then you can set a timer on a a form that triggers all 45 minutes, executing the code you want. How this can be done is explained here: [Timer looping in vba (Access)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34226998/timer-looping-in-vba-access)

You can also replace the AutoExec macro by directly opening the form on startup. This is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3872705/6216216

Comment: Thank you for the response and will look into these links more. :)